# Having 2 empty layout components when list is empty

Tags: android, listview

When my Listview contains no items I have set 2 empty layoutcomponents in my XML. Is it possible to address either one of these components in code? Because the button has to be below the TextView, but when it's not in XML, the app crashes because it finds the TextView first.

My XML looks like this:

```
    <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
    <Button 
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Toon dichtstbijzijnde kantoor" 
    android:gravity="center"/>  

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:text="Er zijn geen jobs die voldoen aan uw criteria..."
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

Update:
with following code it runs perfectly, but the button is not shown...

```
    <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

    <LinearLayout android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/TestText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:text="Er zijn geen jobs die voldoen aan uw criteria..."
    android:gravity="center"/>

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/Test"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Toon dichtstbijzijnde kantoor" 
    /> 
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the Button and the TextView into a LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@android:id/empty">
    <Button />
    <TextView />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I've put it as a sample you must fill the layout properties, the exception is telling you everything - java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #46: You must supply a layout_width attribute.

Comment: That was kind of silly of me. Thank you. However, now I've replaced my button below TextView and gave him `android:id="@+id/Test"` It's not shown. Only TextView is show (also has another ID as empty).

Comment: don't put any other element with id "@android:id/empty", just the layout

Comment: i had misunderstood your last words about the empty ID, anyway, try to set android:orientation="vertical" on the layout, because i think it is putting the button on the right of the textview, and the text view fills the screen becaus of its layout_width="fill_parent" (or replace this with wrap_content, and leave orientation unchanged)